# DateFormatter: dateFormat milliseconds Swift

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I'm writing `DateFormatter`'s `dateFormat` to convert JSON from server to local swift object.
Server would return following.

- 2018-10-07T15:26:33.236Z
- 2018-10-07T15:26:33Z
- 2018-10-07T15:26:33.26Z

Following is my code, but I'm not sure if I can write just one line instead of switch-case conditions (from SWITCH-CASE START to END).

Just one `dateFormat` is ideal regardless of whether returned time has milliseconds or not.
Any advice appreciated.

```
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom{
        let container = try $0.singleValueContainer()
        let dateStr = try container.decode(String.self)
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        formatter.locale = .current
        // *** SWITCH-CASE: START ***
        switch dateStr.utf8.count {
        case 20:
                    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        case 22:
                    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ"
        case 23:
                    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZ"
        case 24:
                    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        default:
                    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        }
        // *** SWITCH-CASE: END ***
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        return formatter.date(from: dateStr)!
    }
```

Comment: Note that you use the same date format "mm" for month and minute – one of them is wrong :)

Comment: Don't check with count. Try converting the string to date by using first date format, If you get nil that means this is not the format, try another in same way.. You just need to convert 3 times in `if, else if` conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it's sufficient to check if the date string contains a period

```
if dateStr.contains(".") {
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ"
} else {
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
}
```

Alternatively use `ISO8601DateFormatter` and remove the milliseconds with Regular Expression, this avoids also to specify `calendar`, `locale` and `timezone`

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let trimmedDateStr = dateStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\.\\d+", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
return formatter.date(from: trimmedDateStr)!
```